# Filtering the lines in a file

Tags: shell, grep

I want to remove the lines from a file which having the word `info` and not having the word `LogUtil`.

`sample.txt` looks like this:

```
this is debug and SparkUtil class
this is info and LogUtil class
this is info with SparkUtil class
this is error and LogUtil class
this is info and RuleUtil class
this is warn and LogUtil class
```

The desired output looks like this:

```
this is debug and SparkUtil class
this is info and LogUtil class
this is error and LogUtil class
this is warn and LogUtil class
```

Any shell command would suffice.

Comment: Please read the description of the "shell" tag. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, the tool you're looking for is e.g. `ack` or `grep`.

Comment: `grep -vf <(grep info sample.txt | grep -v LogUtil) sample.txt` should do the trick. (The process substitution is `bash` specific btw.)

Answer (score -1):

try this naveen

while IFS= read -r line
do
   if [[ "$line" != *"info"* ]] || [[ "$line" == *"LogUtil"* ]]; then
    echo "$line"
  fi
done <